# WCF REST service hosted in Windows service not working without IIS installation

Tags: wcf, rest, iis, windows-services

I have developed a REST service using WCF and hosted it in a windows service and that works fine on a machine which has IIS installed, but not on a machine which does not have IIS. On the machine which has no IIS, if I browse `http://localhost`, it says "cannot display webpage". so do I need to install IIS to get this working, even though the WCF service is not hosted in it?

Answer (score 0):

No, IIS is not required. The reason you can not brows to localhost
 is because that is going to port 80 by default, and because you have no IIS, there is nothing there to direct to to a webpage. (Not unless you had a windows service to take in the http request on port 80 and send back an HTML page, but that would be weird.)

But in short, you do NOT need IIS to run your windows services.